# Can't start mysql server after updating Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-error-2002

**first i have tried to uninstall both of them**

```
root@thaali:/etc/mysql# sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql.cnf
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql.cnf'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql.cnf'
E: Unable to locate package mysql.conf.d
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mysql.conf.d'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql.conf.d'
```

**Then i have tried to install them**

```
root@thaali:/etc/mysql# sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client is already the newest version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

**This is what happen when i tried to restart**

```
root@thaali:/etc/mysql# sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**This is what happened when i try to systemctl**

```
root@thaali:/etc/mysql# systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-29 22:07:43 +0530; 6min ago
  Process: 21283 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
මැයි 29 22:07:43 thaali systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

**This is the error that's throw me when i tried to connect**

```
root@thaali:/etc/mysql# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Can any one please help me to solve this and i have seen in some places i have edit **etc/my.cnf** to fix this in my case i don't have such a file

Comment: What is the output of `ps -aux | grep 'mysql'` ? Have you tried restarting your machine after update?

Comment: `thaali   23546  0.0  0.0  20008   876 pts/1    S+   00:50   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
` this is the out put of that and i haven't try restating i will try that to and update. Thank you very much for replying

Comment: Restating not fixed the issue

Comment: Try `sudo aptitude install mysql-server mysql-client`

Comment: `thaali@thaali:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client is already the newest version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1).
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
`

Comment: use `aptitude` instead of `apt`. It is more robust and sometimes solves the package missing problem.

Comment: `mysql-server is already installed at the requested version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1)
mysql-client is already installed at the requested version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1)
mysql-server is already installed at the requested version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1)
mysql-client is already installed at the requested version (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.19.04.1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
` this what it's says i don't know how to deal with this :(

Answer (score 0):

This one is really weird for I was not dist upgrading. One day it just didn't work.

When I tried `journalctl -xe` I got this

```
    ...
Oct 05 08:51:26 <servername> mysql-systemd-start[10914]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Oct 05 08:51:26 <servername> mysql-systemd-start[10914]: mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
    ...
```

I fixed it by doing this:

`sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files`

`sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql-files/`

`sudo chmod 700 /var/lib/mysql-files/`

`sudo service mysql restart`

Restarting the service didn't actually fix all problems I was having so I ended with rebooting the machine.